# Como enviar 2 arrays/parâmetros através da url?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a tentar enviar dois parâmetros do carrinho de compras através da *url* ,para depois o cliente fazer a confirmação, mas só consigo receber um array na outra página e não sei como fazer para receber dois.

Quero enviar a *quantidade de produtos* e os *id_produtos* para na pagina outra página, onde o usuário vai confirmar para depois inserir na *banco de dados*.

Na pagina do carrinho

```
<?php
**// array para guardar todos os valores que estão no carrinho
$emparray[] = $product['id_produto'];
$quant[] = $product['quantidade'];
...

// transformar a array numa associação de parâmetros para a url
$query = http_build_query($emparray);
testar = http_build_query($quant);

$cart_box .= '<div class="cart-products-total">Total : '.$total.' € <u><a href="index.php?page=confirmar_encomenda&'.$query.'&'.$testar.'"  title="Verifica o carrinho e faz checkout">Concluir</a></u></div>';

?>
```

Na outra pagina, é assim que recebo os valores. De forma a enviar na confirmação do formulário.

```
<?php
$teste=$_GET;
echo $teste;

foreach($teste as $value){
   echo' <input type='text" name="result[]" value="'. $value.'">';
}
?>
```

Mas desta forma ele só mostra o ultimo *array* e já tentei *N* formas para receber os dois separados mas não consegui.

Comment: olá, estás a construir mal a array, a passar mal os parâmetros, e também a sobrecarregar a recepção, lê [isto aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas coisas:

1. Evite passar esse tipo de dados de compra por `GET`, use o método `POST`. Além de ser mais seguro, tem um [limite na quantidade de caracteres que você pode passar por GET](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP8MqZsOHSAhVDkJAKHQmZA9UQFggeMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F417142%2Fwhat-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers&usg=AFQjCNEuyHWA7lzU8D-SAqjEgMC4zql0DA&sig2=b3SM1K9Z0mkWr-HMZEGENA&bvm=bv.150120842,d.Y2I) de 2083 caracteres. Parece muito, mas se seu cliente estiver comprando 100 produtos diferentes pode muito bem ultrapassar esse limite.
2. Quando você define os arrays que vão passar por `http_build_query` você está passando o valor diretamente, então as array resultantes devem ser arrays com índices numerados ao invés de associativas, por isso o `GET` deve estar sobrescrevendo os parâmetros que você está passando pra ele, ou seja: o resultado na URL deve ser mais de um parâmetro com a mesma chave: `?page=confirmar_encomenda&0=1344&0=2`. Ao invés de usar duas arrays, por que não passar a array produtos que contém todas as informações?

`$query = http_build_query($product);`

Comment: adição de produtos num carrinho, pode ser seguramente efectuada usando `GET`, já que é apenas adicionar, e se o site tiver protecção conta furto, isso será tão seguro quanto respirar - ou não. Mas vê-se logo a ideia pois não ? Aproveitando a pergunta, lê [isto aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), talvez entendas melhor o que faz o `http_build_query`.

Comment: E na pagina seguinte como separo os dados, caso envie tudo?

Comment: O nome das propriedades no ``$_GET`` vai ser diferente. Então ``$_GET['quantidade']`` vai trazer a quantidade de produtos. Ou ``$_POST`` se você preferir.